# Variable assignment in KornShell

Tags: shell, ksh

I've an weird error when trying to assign the value to a variable into another. The initial variable value contains `'` signs at the beginning and at the end.

Here is the code :

```
server = $(uname -n)
passpre = "'HPre2053#'"
passmon = "'MonH2053#'"
mdp=""

echo ${server}

if [[ "$server" = "cly1024" ]]; 
then
    echo "Dentro Pre"
    mdp = $(passpre)
    echo $mdp
    logit "Exécution du script sur Pre. Mot de passe choisi."
elif [[ "$server" = "pcy4086" ]]; 
then
    echo "Dentro MON"
    mdp = ${passmon}
    logit "Exécution du script sur MON. Mot de passe choisi."
fi
```

Code error :

```
cly1024
Dentro Pre
modMDPconfig.ksh[51]: passpre:  not found
modMDPconfig.ksh[51]: mdp:  not found
```

Line 51 is where i do the variable assignation `mdp = $(passpre)`

Comment: `mdp = $(passpre)` is not doing an assignment at all. It runs a command `mdp` with the first argument `=` and the second command the output of running `passpre` as a command. Given this, the error message it gives you is entirely descriptive of the problem.

Comment: Note, by the way, that quotes-as-data (in `"'foo'"`, the `'` quotes are data, and the `"` quotes are syntax) are never able to substitute for syntactical quotes. When you do a parameter expansion, data **always** stays data -- it can't turn into syntax unless you're then explicitly running that data through an evaluation pass, and doing so is very bad form for security reasons.

Comment: A variable assignment in the `sh` family **must** consist of a single string containing an `=` sign.  On the left side must be a valid variable name (alphanumeric + underscore), the right side can contain anything, but whitespace must be quoted.  The normal difference for `"` ... `"` and `'` ... `'` quoting apply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
var = value
```

This is right:

```
var=value
```

Do not put spaces around the `=` operator in assignments.

---

A corrected form of this script follows:

```
server=$(uname -n)
passpre="'HPre2053#'"
passmon="'MonH2053#'"
mdp=""

echo "$server"

if [[ "$server" = "cly1024" ]]; then
    echo "Dentro Pre"
    mdp=$passpre
    echo "$mdp"
    logit "Exécution du script sur Pre. Mot de passe choisi."
elif [[ "$server" = "pcy4086" ]]; then
    echo "Dentro MON"
    mdp=$passmon
    logit "Exécution du script sur MON. Mot de passe choisi."
fi
```